# How can I retrieve target properties from a CMake-generated buildsystem?

Tags: cmake, target

Suppose I have an existing project and it's cmake-configured build directory. How can I retreive some target's properties using this build, provided that I know the target name? I tried creating a separate script like this

```
get_target_property(VAR target property)
```

but it fails with error

```
Command get_target_property() is not scriptable
```

Are there any other methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently get_target_property() can be called only when configuring a build directory with cmake. I am not aware of any method of getting targets properties on already configured build directory. But if modifying existing CMakeFiles.txt is an option, there is a workaround.

You can try locating target definition, get the target's properties there and dump them into a text file. Then, this file can be then used in any other scripts called after build directory configuration is done.

This example illustrates this workaround:

```
add_executable(app ${app_sources}) 
set_target_properties(app PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS SOME_DEF=1)

get_target_property(compile_defs app COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
file(WRITE app_compile_defs.txt ${compile_defs})
```

Be sure to use `get_target_property` after every property changes for given target in CMakeFiles.txt are done. Otherwise you can miss something as in example below.

```
add_executable(app ${app_sources}) 
set_target_properties(app PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS SOME_DEF=1)

get_target_property(compile_defs app COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
file(WRITE app_compile_defs.txt ${compile_defs})

set_target_properties(app PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ANOTHER_DEF=0)
```

In the example above, the `ANOTHER_DEF=0` definition will not be listed in `app_compile_defs.txt`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly that's not an option, but thanks for the idea!