# How to add external library in android studio with cmake?

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to link live555.so and .h files with an Android project using cMake. If i don't use absolute path i'm getting error.

My **cMake** file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

include_directories( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/live555/include )

add_library( live555 SHARED IMPORTED )

set_target_properties( live555 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/live555/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/live555.so)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
         native-lib

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
          log-lib

          # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
          # you want CMake to locate.
          log )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   native-lib
                   android
                   live555
                   ${log-lib} )
```

And **error**:

> Error:error:
>   '../../../../src/main/jniLibs/live555/lib/armeabi-v7a/live555.so',
>   needed by
>   '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so',
>   missing and no known rule to make it

Comment: Did you copy the .so into the `src/main/jniLibs/live555/lib/armeabi-v7a` directory?

Comment: Yes i did. If I change " ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}" to absolute path it accepts otherwise gives that error. So I wonder if I have to use a system path like /usr/local... ?

Comment: Use `message(STATUS ${PROJECT_SRC_DIR})` before set_target_propeties, then try to get the property after set to check it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881408/retrieve-target-properties-from-cmake-build

Answer (score 2):

`${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` is the directory where the main CMakeList.txt file resides. That's typically **app/src/main/cpp**. You can work out the correct relative path now.

This means that you can simply write

```
include_directories( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/live555/include )

add_library( live555 SHARED IMPORTED )

set_target_properties( live555 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/live555/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/live555.so)
```