# Adding VTK to Android Studio 3.3 project with NDK r17c

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk, vtk

I am trying to add the VTK to my native Android project in AS 3.3. I have installed the NDK r17c. I would like to use some of the VTK functionalities in my native application. Also, I am using gradle 3.3.2 for building my android project and CMake 3.6.4 for building native side of the project. My problem is that I haven't found a suitable tutorial (I am new to Android native development) for importing the VTK into the Android Studio using all building tools that I have described. Is there a way to do that?
Also, I would like to add that I am using Windows 7 OS.

EDIT: I had updated my CMakeLists.txt file with some lines I had found relevant in the official example (https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/tree/master/Examples/Android). I would like to use VTK inside my native-lib library:

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)



# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

link_directories(src/main/jni/japi src/main/jni/acquisition)

file(GLOB native_SRC
        "src/main/jni/japi/*.h"
        "src/main/jni/japi/*.cpp"
        )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        native-lib

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        ${native_SRC})


file(GLOB acquisition_SRC
        "src/main/jni/acquisition/*.h"
        "src/main/jni/acquisition/*.cpp"
        )
#file(GLOB acquisition_SRC
#        "src/main/jni/acquisition/*.h"
#        )

add_library( acquisition-lib STATIC ${acquisition_SRC})
#add_library(
#        acquisition-lib
#
#        STATIC
#
#        src/main/jni/acquisition/test-lib.h
#        src/main/jni/acquisition/test-lib.cpp)

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
          log-lib

          # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
          # you want CMake to locate.
          log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
           native-lib

           # Links the target library to the log library
           # included in the NDK.
           ${log-lib})

target_link_libraries( native-lib acquisition-lib )

set(OpenCV_DIR "../opencv/src/sdk/native/jni")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "OpenCV libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
target_link_libraries(native-lib ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(acquisition-lib ${OpenCV_LIBS})
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a")



##ADDED for including the VTK

find_package(VTK COMPONENTS
        vtkInteractionStyle
        vtkRenderingOpenGL2
        vtkRenderingFreeType
        vtkTestingCore
        vtkTestingRendering
        )
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

target_link_libraries( native-lib ${VTK_LIBRARIES} )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it took me about a week to get this working, but it paid off. I will list all the things I needed to do to be able to use VTK in my android application.

**STEP 1: Building VTK on Linux machine**

Because Android is based on the Linux OS, you need to build libraries in `.a` or `.so` format. To do this, the easiest thing to do is to build VTK on Linux machine. So you have to install Linux to your machine eather as dual boot or, as in my case, install a virtual machine that runs Linux.

After that, you need to install all the thing needed to download and build VTK for Android. Here is the list of the things you need to download and install to your Linux machine:

1. Download and install the Android NDK- I downloaded the same version that I am using in my Android Studio - r17c
2. Download and install the Android SDK , i.e. Android Studio
3. Download and install ANT
4. Download and install Java
5. Download and install CMake - also after I installed it, I needed to run: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential`
6. Download and install Git
7. Install OpenGL - I used: `sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev`
8. Define `ANDROID_NDK` environment variable - point it to unzipped android NDK folder
9. Define `ANT_HOME` environment variable - point it to unzipped ANT folder
10. Define `JAVA_HOME` environment variable - point it to unzipped Java JRE folder
11. Define `ANDROID_SDK` environment variable - point it to the location of Android/Sdk folder
12. Define `CMAKE_HOME` environment variable - point it to the location of your installed CMake
13. Add to `PATH` enviroment variable: `ANT_HOME/bin`, `JAVA_HOME/bin`, `ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools`, `ANDROID_SDK/tools`, `CMAKE_HOME/bin`

After the installation of the all the needed tools above, you need to download the VTK source code using git:

1. Create an 'vtk' folder somewhere
2. `cd vtk`
3. `git clone https://github.com/Kitware/VTK.git`

Now, you can go and build the VTK:

1. `mkdir vtk/vtk-android`
2. `cd vtk-android`
3. `ccmake ../VTK`
4. press c (configure)
5. press c (configure)
6. press q (quit)
7. `cmake -DVTK_ANDROID_BUILD=ON -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=23 -DANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a ../VTK`   - here I defined the 23 api level because that is what I am using in my applicatin. Also, here is where you define the architecture ABI of your targeted devices. My device is arm64-v8a so I am using that. In order to build VTK for other architectures, you will need to build for every each one of them. Also, you can edit this in the next step!
8. `ccmake ../VTK`
9. OPTIONAL: at this point, you can define additional modules you need in your application. If you just skip this step, the modules (.a files) you will get are:

   vtkCommonColor, vtkCommonComputationalGeometry, vtkCommonCore,
   vtkCommonDataModel, vtkCommonExecutionModel, vtkCommonMath, vtkCommonMisc,
   vtkCommonSystem, vtkCommonTransforms, vtkDICOMParser, vtkdoubleconversion, 
   vtkexpat, vtkFiltersCore, vtkFiltersExtraction, vtkFiltersGeneral, 
   vtkFiltersGeometry, vtkFiltersHybrid, vtkFiltersModeling, vtkFiltersSources, 
   vtkFiltersStatistics, vtkfreetype, vtkglew, vtkImagingCore, 
   vtkImagingFourier, vtkImagingMath, vtkImagingSources, vtkInfovisCore, 
   vtkInteractionStyle, vtkIOCore vtkIOGeometry, vtkIOImage, vtkIOInfovis, 
   vtkIOLegacy, vtkIOPLY, vtkIOXML, vtkIOXMLParser, vtkjpeg, vtkjsoncpp, 
   vtklibxml2, vtklz4, vtklzma, vtkmetaio, vtkParallelCore, vtkpng, 
   vtkRenderingCore, vtkRenderingFreeType, vtkRenderingOpenGL2, 
   vtkRenderingVolume, vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL2, vtksys, vtkTestingRendering, 
   vtktiff, vtkWrappingTools, vtkzlib

If these modules are not sufficient for you, you need to add some lines to VTK/CMake/vtkAndroid.cmake file because there the build for android is defined. Lines you add must look like:

```
-DVTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_[name-of-the-module]:STRING=YES
```

You can find out all possible `name-of-the-module` values if you press t (toggle) and scroll to VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_... part of the configuration.

10. c (configue)
11. g (generate)
12. `make`

Ok, so the build process starts. On my laptop it took ~30mins (I assigned 3GB of RAM to the virtual machine).

**STEP 2 : Importing the VTK to the Android Studio**

After the build process is finished, you need to copy the folder `vtk/vtk-android/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android` to the your Windows machine.
The folder `lib` contains the build VTK library as a set of static libraries (.a files), and the folder `include` contains all the header files of the VTK you neeed to get the VTK working in full.

Now, in your Android Studio project, create a new Android Library module called `vtk`.
Create the `src/main/jni` folder and inside that folder copy the `lib` and `include` folder described above.

In `jni` folder crate an `vtk-lib.cpp` file which will serve as an interface from your Java code to the VTK library. An example may be:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <vtkConeSource.h>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_link_to_your_java_function(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /*this*/) {

    vtkConeSource *cone = vtkConeSource::New();
    cone->SetHeight(3.0);
    cone->Delete();

}
```

In the `build.gradle` file of your `vtk` module, add this lines:

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11"
                arguments "-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions",
                        "-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_shared"
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
    }

    ...

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

After that, to the `jni` folder add a `CMakeLists.txt` file which will be used for building the module:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(LIB_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/${ANDROID_ABI})

add_library(vtk-common-color STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(vtk-common-color
    PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${LIB_DIR}/libvtkCommonColor-8.90.a)

#53 more libraries from lib folder

add_library( vtk-lib SHARED ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/vtk-lib.cpp)

target_include_directories(vtk-lib PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

target_link_libraries(
    vtk-lib
    -Wl,--start-group -L ${TARGET_OUT}
    vtk-common-color
    #53 more libraries names
    -Wl,--end-group
)
```

And that's it, voila!

Comment: hi, I build success and runing success, and there is no any image display but only the black screen, I import example which from official gitlab's Example/Android/JavaVTK , the url is https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/tree/v9.1.0/Examples/Android/JavaVTK , can you help me? sorry for my poor english!

Answer (score 0):

You can 
 start with the official example [on GitHub](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/tree/master/Examples/Android/NativeVTK):

> NativeVTK is built around the
>   Android native interface and does not have any Java code associated with it.
>   Any unser interface elements would need to be created in C++ using regular
>   VTK widgets or other OpenGL elements. This is best for applications that
>   are mainly focused on rendering or visualization with very minimal user
>   interface. In this example all the key code is in jni/main.cxx and it will
>   look very much like the regular VTK code you are used to.

It doesn't use Android Studio, and for good! Loading huge amounts of 3rd party native code into Android Studio is both useless and frustrating. It is much better to have such libraries compiled with their native build tools, and only import small modules that require lots of changes and/or interactive debugging.

Comment: ok, so you are saying that VTK is already contained in NDK? if so, how do I use it, i.e. how do I include some of the VTK headers inside my c/c++ code? I tried updating my CMakeLists.txt file with some of lines I had found usable in official example. Please check my updated question with CMakeLists content

Comment: No, I am not saying that. You must download and build VTK separately. The example (I have added the correct link) shows how to use VTK with NDK.

Comment: Ok, I realized that. I had installed Cmake, downloaded VTK sources and will try building it with Visual Studio 2017. Since I am on Windows, will I be able to import the library to the Android Studio? Everywhere I looked, it always says "do this on Linux or OSX. The process on Windows is complicated"

Comment: No, you must build with Android NDK. Well, Visual Studio provides integration with NDK, but this will be hard to apply for VTK, as far as I understand. If you cannot run the cross-platform build scripts for VTK from Windows command-line, consider using WSL command line. You will need a Linux-64 version of NDK for that.

Comment: I will try building VTK on Linux, how you described and how it is described in the official example. After it is done building, what should I do with it? Should I copy the built .so files to my Android Studio project and use them as you had described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52669289/7801515)? If so, do I need to copy all the built files or only a part I need? How to determine which .so files I need to copy/import? According to header files I am using or? Sorry for bothering, I am new to native android

Comment: To be on the safe side, copy all built .so files from Linux to your project. After everything is working, you may try to remove some, to reduce the size of the APK.

Comment: I have built the VTK and copied the .so files to my project. Now, do I need to copy every single header file from the VTK source tree to use the functionalities? Because I have tried that and it wouldn't compile due to too many errors (some datatypes cannot be resolved etc...) I had checked if I was missing some header files, but not one!

Comment: Typically, you simply point your includes path to whatever an external library exposes, without copying the headers.

Comment: I'm having another problem regarding the linking the imported libraries. I had posted my new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56296901/linking-vtk-with-ndk-build-on-ndk-r17c-results-with-undefined-references-error)