# Linking VTK with ndk-build on NDK r17c results with 'undefined references' errors

Tags: android, android-ndk, vtk, ndk-build

I had built [VTK](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK) on Linux with Android NDK r17c and the result was 54 static (.a) libraries of total 600+ MB. Now, I had imported these librarires to my AndroidStudio 3.3 project and I would like to use the built libraries in my native code. In Android Studio I am using the same version of the NDK (r17c).

In AndroidStudio I had created new module for using the VTK and inside that module I am using ndk-build for building the library. The structure of the module is:

```
...
|--jni/
|--|--include/
|--|--|--vtkAbstractArray.h
|--|--|--vtkAbstractCellLinks.h
|--|--|-- ...
|--|--lib/
|--|--|--arm64-v8a/
|--|--|--|--libvtkCommonColor-8.9.0.a
|--|--|--|--libvtkCommonComputationalGeometry-8.9.0.a
|--|--|--|--...
|--|--Application.mk
|--|--Android.mk
|--|--vtk-lib.cpp
```

I am using the VTK library in my **vtk-lib.cpp** file (which I am accessing from Java code).

In order just to get this to work, I wasn't building the library for all of the supported android architectures (but only for my **arm64-v8a** device), so I defined an **Application.mk** file like this:

```
APP_STL := c++_static
API_ABI := arm64-v8a
```

In my **Android.mk** file, I had defined **54 modules** with `PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY` (one for each of the 54 built .a files). In the end, I am building a `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY` with vtk-lib.cpp file to be accessible from Java:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

#prepare vtk-common-color
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := vtk-common-color
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libvtkCommonColor-8.90.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

#...53 more modules for every .a static library

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := vtk-lib.cpp
LOCAL_MODULE     := vtk-lib
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := vtk-common-color ... # 53 more module names
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES := rtti exceptions
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += --std=c++11
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When I try to build the application a get a bunch of the errors regarding the `undefined reference`  as shown below:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process [some path]\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk- 
build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null 
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=[some path]\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK= 
[some path]\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a 
NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 
NDK_OUT=[some path]/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj 
NDK_LIBS_OUT=[some path]\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib [some 
path]build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/arm64-v8a/libvtk-lib.so}

[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : vtk-lib <= vtk-lib.cpp
[arm64-v8a] SharedLibrary  : libvtk-lib.so
[some path]/src/main/jni/lib/arm64-v8a/libvtkFiltersSources- 
8.90.a(vtkConeSource.cxx.o): In function `vtkConeSource::New()':
[some path ON LINUX]/VTK/Filters/Sources/vtkConeSource.cxx:30: undefined 
reference to `vtkObjectBase::InitializeObjectBase()'
[some path]/src/main/jni/lib/arm64-v8a/libvtkFiltersSources- 
8.90.a(vtkConeSource.cxx.o): In function 
`vtkConeSource::vtkConeSource(int)':
[some path ON LINUX]/VTK/Filters/Sources/vtkConeSource.cxx:35: undefined 
reference to `vtkPolyDataAlgorithm::vtkPolyDataAlgorithm()'

#etc etc many more errors
```

I had came across [this github thread](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/545) so I had tried using the `LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES` instead of `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES`, different versions of `LOCAL_LDLIBS`  and `LOCAL_LDFLAGS` but still no luck.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using **CMake** insted of ndk-build.

I needed to add this code to my module's **build.gradle**:

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11"
                arguments "-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions",
                        "-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_shared"
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
    }

    ...

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

And, my **CMakeLists.txt** looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(LIB_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/${ANDROID_ABI})

add_library(vtk-common-color STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(vtk-common-color
    PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${LIB_DIR}/libvtkCommonColor-8.90.a)

#53 more libraries

add_library( vtk-lib SHARED ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/vtk-lib.cpp)

target_include_directories(vtk-lib PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

target_link_libraries(
    vtk-lib
    -Wl,--start-group -L ${TARGET_OUT}
    vtk-common-color
    #53 more libraries names
    -Wl,--end-group
)
```

Comment: yes,I found that -Wl,--start-group worked,but the official Example/Android is not working but just black Screen.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely not circular dependency, but only wrong order on the list.

If all *undefined references* are from VTK libraries, you can simply find the working order for LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES, eliminating these link errors one by one. E.g. the first error means that `vtkCommonCore` must go behind `vtkFiltersSources`, the second – that `vtkCommonExecutionModel` should also go after `vtkFiltersSources`.

VTK supports CMake, so if you use CMake instead of **Android.mk** build scripts, it may be easier to achieve the correct dependency order.

Comment: I ended up using CMake. Thank you for the help! I will post the resolution in an answer.