# How to print current compilation flags that are set with target_compile_options()?

Tags: makefile, cmake, build-automation, compiler-flags

I am trying to print compilation flags that are set for target. The best scenario is to print a line with current flags on configure and compilation times, but if it's impossible, then on configure time only (or compilation only) (acceptable solution).

This is my testing .c file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And CMakeLists.txt:

```c
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(cmake_gcc_options_try_c C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(cmake_gcc_options_try_c main.c)

target_compile_options(cmake_gcc_options_try_c 
                       PUBLIC -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors)

# This fails
message("-- Current compiler flags CMAKE_C_FLAGS are: ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
message("-- Current compiler flags C_FLAGS are: ${C_FLAGS}")
```

and

```bash
cmake . && make
```

Gives this output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Current compiler flags CMAKE_C_FLAGS are: 
-- Current compiler flags C_FLAGS are: 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/Projects/cmake-gcc-options-try-c
Scanning dependencies of target cmake_gcc_options_try_c
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmake_gcc_options_try_c.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable cmake_gcc_options_try_c
[100%] Built target cmake_gcc_options_try_c
```

Why `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `C_FLAGS` are printed as they were undefined?

How to achieve this print on `make` command:

```
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmake_gcc_options_try_c.dir/main.c.o
[ 50%] Current compiler flags are: -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors -std=gnu11
[100%] Linking C executable cmake_gcc_options_try_c
[100%] Built target cmake_gcc_options_try_c
```

?

**Update:** [Viktor Sergienko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207791/victor-sergienko) came with a working solution, but one problem with this it's not so pretty print:
[image]
Any thoughts how to make it to be in format of other prints? E. g. :

```
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmake_gcc_options_try_c.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable cmake_gcc_options_try_c
[100%] Current compiler flags are: -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors -std=gnu11
[100%] Built target cmake_gcc_options_try_c
```

Second problem is that `-std=gnu11` is not printed (but it is enabled with `set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)` and `set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)`)

Comment: "Why `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `C_FLAGS` are printed as they were undefined?" - Variable `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` is just **empty** in your case. It doesn't accumulate values added with `target_compile_options` - the latter options are come in form of target's **properties**. See that question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39501481/3440745. If you want extract the target's compile definitions (e.g. for print them), you need to extract corresponded properties, like in that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24921921/3440745.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use:

- [COMPILE_OPTIONS target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html) to get **target-specific** compilation flags;
- [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) with a POST_BUILD option to print any variable;

This gave me a `;-list` of the options both at configure and compile times:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(cmake_gcc_options_try_c C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(cmake_gcc_options_try_c main.c)

target_compile_options(cmake_gcc_options_try_c 
                       PUBLIC -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors)

get_target_property(MAIN_CFLAGS cmake_gcc_options_try_c COMPILE_OPTIONS)
# also see: COMPILE_DEFINITIONS INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
message("-- Target compiler flags are: ${MAIN_CFLAGS}")

add_custom_command(TARGET cmake_gcc_options_try_c POST_BUILD
COMMAND echo built with the flags: ${MAIN_CFLAGS})
```

Update after question was updated: to get C/CXX standard, look up [C_STANDARD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/C_STANDARD.html). If you wonder why CMake sets `-gnu` variant of the flag, it's because of [`CXX_EXTENSIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_EXTENSIONS.html) is `ON` by default.

Update2: To get the full compiler/linker commands for every source file as a JSON file, set [CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html) to `ON` (only works in CMake 3.5+, `make` and `ninja` generators). Credit for this piece goes to Florian's comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623354/get-build-command-or-all-compiler-flags-that-will-be-used-to-build-a-target).

Comment: The update 1) is not set with `target_compile_options`, the update 2) is a different question added post factum; I'm afraid there's no way to access CMake compilation progress in compile time, or print messages through CMake.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't mentioned that I want all flags to be printed, but if you will take a look on history, in the first version there is a line `[ 50%] Current compiler flags are: -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors -std=gnu11` (I meant it implicitly). Otherwise, what is the point of printing part of the flags? :)
Btw, cmake creates a file `flags.make` and there are all flags somehow.

Comment: If you want ALL of the compilation flags, then your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623354/get-build-command-or-all-compiler-flags-that-will-be-used-to-build-a-target. Printing format or lack of thereof is, though, completely out of scope of the question, especially that you have marked it canonical. `flags.make` is an implementation detail that is different in ninja, and doesn't exist in other generators.

Comment: _"CMake only sets -gnu variant of the flag"_: that's not true, you can use the non-gnu variant with [CXX_EXTENSIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_EXTENSIONS.html)

Comment: Thank you! That's why it was always set. Updating the answer.