# How to find the target that exposes some library as PUBLIC/INTERFACE

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, linker, ninja

In my quite large CPP project (CMake/ninja) some library (maybe third party) exposes `zstd` as `public` or `interface`. Since I've switched to `vcpkg` the linker fails since it cant find the library `-lzstd`. I found all possible places that may expose the `zstd` library as PUBLIC and switched to PRIVATE, but I still can see the linker tries to link with `-lzstd`. Is there a way, for example, by analyzing CMake or ninja files to figure out where this `-lzstd` comes from? Maybe the linker can somehow assist in figuring it out?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70003456/find-out-why-cmake-adds-specific-link-flags

Comment: Not sure if this'll work, but you can probably recursively go through [INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES.html) and [LINK_LIBRARIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_LIBRARIES.html#prop_tgt:LINK_LIBRARIES) starting from your main project until you eventually find zstd.

Comment: @AlanBirtles not sure useful, I do see the zstd linked into third party, but this thirdparty uses `target_link_libraries` with PRIVATE to link with zstd, so I guess it cant expose it

Comment: If the third party library isn't a shared library then it'll still pass the link to `zstd` onto targets that link to it even if it's `PRIVATE`

Comment: @AlanBirtles it is static library... wasnt aware it works this way. interesting... any workaround for this problem? Except switching to dynamic library?

Comment: If you link to the third party library and it requires zstd then you'll have to link to it. Why not just install it?

Comment: This is what I did in the end, later on will rework the third party to use `vcpkg` instead of having zillion submodules. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I wonder if https://stackoverflow.com/a/22035388/11107541 could be of any help. maybe not if zstd isn't a target.

Comment: Looks like it is the same as @AlanBirtles first comment