# How to preprocess the headers in cmake

Tags: gcc, cmake, msvc12

I would like to preprocess public headers of a target in a same way when they are getting preprocessed at the compilation of the target.

It is possible to get the preprocessed source files of a target using `/P` for msvc or `-E` for gcc.

I'm also able to preprocess the header files using add_custom_command but I don't know what I need for to preprocess them same as they are preprocessed in the compilation of the target.

Comment: I do not understand. How does preprocessing the header differs from preprocessing the header "in the compilation of the target"? Which target?

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk, in cmake there are targets for compilation and they can have macro definition or special compilation arguments which affect the way to preprocess(I'm not sure of this). So what I want to do is preprocessing the header files of a target myself but the point is I want to preprocess them exactly while they are being preprocessed in the compilation of the target.

Comment: So extracting  the flags from the cmake target and use it for your custom command? ex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56104607/how-to-print-current-compilation-flags-that-are-set-with-target-compile-options . But if this is for debugging or for IDE, it is easier to generate compile_command.json and extract flags from there.